# Kubectl 'broken pipe' and 'timeout occurred' issue with minIO deployment

Tags: kubernetes, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, minio

Everytime I try accessing my minIO console via the browser with a port-forward, the connection will work briefly with multiple connection messages of:

```
Handling connection for 9000
Handling connection for 42935
Handling connection for 42935
Handling connection for 42935
Handling connection for 42935
Handling connection for 42935
Handling connection for 42935
...
```

Then a moment later, this error message

`E0128 18:22:01.801739   40952 portforward.go:378] error copying from remote stream to local connection: readfrom tcp6 [::1]:42935->[::1]:50796: write tcp6 [::1]:42935->[::1]:50796: write: broken pipe`

Before it finally spamming with multiple messages of:

```
E0128 18:22:31.738313   40952 portforward.go:346] error creating error stream for port 42935 -> 42935: Timeout occurred
Handling connection for 42935
E0128 18:22:32.120930   40952 portforward.go:346] error creating error stream for port 42935 -> 42935: write tcp 192.168.0.16:50776->34.133.9.102:443: write: broken pipe
Handling connection for 42935
E0128 18:22:32.574837   40952 portforward.go:346] error creating error stream for port 42935 -> 42935: write tcp 192.168.0.16:50776->34.133.9.102:443: write: broken pipe
...
```

Here's my deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: minio-deployment
  namespace: minio-ns
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: minio
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: minio
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: minio
          image: minio/minio
          args:
            - server
            - /data
            - --console-address
            - ":42935"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: minio-pv-storage
              mountPath: /data
      volumes:
        - name: minio-pv-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: minio-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minio-service
  namespace: minio-ns
spec:
  selector:
    app: minio
  ports:
    - name: minio
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
    - name: minio-console
      port: 42935
      targetPort: 42935
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: minio-pv-claim
  namespace: minio-ns
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

I changed the minio-service type to LoadBalancer (from ClusterIP) to access the console via the browser along with adding the --console-address flag and exposing the necessary port. This worked in allowing the minIO console to show despite being in a constant loading state. If I try to login, it will just refresh until crashing/timing out

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. The issue didn't have anything to do with my actual code.

https://github.com/minio/console/issues/2539